# Trouble performing a SQL insert using selects where more than 1 row is to be inserted

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I'm not the strongest SQL developer (kinda new) but I thought I could do what I'm trying to do, but I'm receiving an error.

Basically, I'm trying to perform a mass insert based on some selects. The value of the first select in the statement below returns 1 groupid, but the 2nd statement returns a few hundred requestcategory id's.  I am trying to perform these few hundred inserts with the statement below:

```
INSERT
INTO M_GROUPREQUESTCATEGORY
(
    GROUPID,
    REQUESTCATEGORYID
)
VALUES
(
    (select groupid from esaws.m_group where name = 'Administration Group'),
    (select requestcategoryid from esaws.m_grouprequestcategory where groupid = (select groupid from esaws.m_group where name = 'Customer Service Group'))
);
```

My issue is, SQL is returning the following error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and what I need to change to get this working?

EDIT:  To be clear, im trying to come up with a way to NOT have to write a few hundred indivdual inserts.

Comment: The error is VERY clear. You're trying to use a subselect in a context where it is only permitted to return ONE row of data, but is returning 2+ rows. Since you've got 3 subselects there, that's the closest we can come to helping.

Comment: i understand that, but i guess what im asking is, how do i alter my query to get this to do what im trying to do

Comment: Well, we can't help you. We have no idea what your subqueries are doing. You'll have to figure out which one of those 3 subselects is/are returning multiple rows.

Comment: If multiple rows are returned by the subquery - what do you want to do? You should try write a single select statement that returns the results you'd like to insert first.

Comment: Marc, if you read what i wrote in the original post, you would see that i am telling you the FIRST select returns 1 groupid, but the SECOND select returns multiple request categories.

Comment: gvee, i guess what im asking is, How do i do that?  as i said, im kinda new to sql and dont know how to create the statements to do the few hundred inserts that im asking for.

Comment: @user3394338 the key is to start with SELECT statements that return the data set you want to insert. Once you've got your SELECT correct the next step is trivial.

Comment: @user3394338 The answer I just posted shows one way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this is what you want:

```
INSERT
INTO M_GROUPREQUESTCATEGORY
(
    GROUPID,
    REQUESTCATEGORYID
)
select      DISTINCT G.groupid, R.requestcategoryid 
from        esaws.m_group G
Cross Join  esaws.m_grouprequestcategory R
where       G.name = 'Administration Group'
and         R.groupid = (
                select groupid 
                from esaws.m_group 
                where name = 'Customer Service Group')
and NOT EXISTS(Select * From esaws.m_grouprequestcategory R2
               Where  R2.GroupID = G.GroupID
               And    R2.requestcategoryid = R.requestcategoryid)
;
```

Which basically is Copying all of the request categories from the 'Customer Service Group' to the 'Administration Group', if I understand it correctly.

Comment: thanks barry.  when i try to run this, im getting "SQL command not properly ended".  i cant see what we're leaving out.....

Comment: im trying to get this to run but i cant see why it thinks its not properly ended

Comment: @user3394338 I get it in SQL Fiddle too, no idea why.  I'm going to try to ask it as a separate question...

Comment: @user3394338  What are you using to execute these commands in Oracle?  There's some feeling that this might be an interface issue.

Comment: im using Sql Developer 4.0. Its the only thing we use here at work

Comment: @user3394338 Try this new version.  I have removed the `As` keywords, which may help.

Comment: thanks barry.  with the new code, i get the error message: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ESAWS.PK_M_GROUP_REQUESTCATEGORY) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
i dont understand this message, since the table has different entries with the samegroupid.

Comment: @user3394338 It's telling you that that Administration Group already has some of the GroupIDs you are trying to insert.

Comment: @user3394338 I have updated my answer with changes that should address this.

Comment: RBarry, i believe that did it!    Thank you so much.. you are a godsend!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries in the select statement must evaluate to a single value, or else you will get this error. This makes sense since you are looking to fill the value for one field.

So when you say 'but the 2nd statement returns a few hundred requestcategory id's', then that's the error right there. You need to have it be only 1 for each result.

Comment: ss781:  I am trying to avoid having to write several hundred inserts, and attempting to do it in 1 statement.  What im doing is clearly wrong, but i cant figure out what i need to do in order to not have to write hundreds of inserts

Comment: SS781 - this should not be an answer, but a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of doing Cross-Join

The way  I understand your requirement is - You want to copy all groupIds from Admin Group to Customer Service Group - Based on that you want to have a Cross-Tab Join.

```
INSERT INTO  schema.tgt_table_name 
    WITH groupid AS
         (SELECT groupid
            FROM esaws.m_group
           WHERE NAME = 'Administration Group'),
         requestcategoryid AS
         (SELECT requestcategoryid
            FROM esaws.m_grouprequestcategory
           WHERE groupid = (SELECT groupid
                              FROM esaws.m_group
                             WHERE NAME = 'Customer Service Group'))
    SELECT groupid.groupid, requestcategoryid.requestcategoryid
      FROM groupid, requestcategoryid
```

Comment: Sandeep:  The code you supplied returns the hundred of records i want to insert exactly.  My question, however, is how do i take what your query above returns, and change them into INSERTS instead of showing me on screen?

Comment: added insert statement